# Bitmap Overlay not working properly in Pie

Tags: android, bitmap, android-9.0-pie

Following overly function working in up to android version 8 but not working in pie :

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
return bmOverlay;
}
```

Desired output getting in below Pie : function's first parameter is output of picture capture and second parameter is bitmap of header view.

[image: Desired output getting in below Pie]

Pie output :

[image]

View to Bitmap done by :

```
public static Bitmap viewtoBitmap(View view,int width,int hight){
        Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(width,hight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: How have you determined that that method is the issue? Have you checked that the `Bitmap`s you're passing into that method are what you're expecting them to be? Also, any particular reason you're using two different `drawBitmap()` methods?

Comment: In pie's output whole Image draw from header view bitmap (base on it's colour).so I think method is issue. I am using two drawBitmap() for draw two different bitmap on one canvas.

Comment: Yes, but why do you think the problem is in the code you've posted? How do you know that the `Bitmap` you're passing in for `bmp2` isn't wrong? You aren't doing any resizing in the posted code, so I would be more inclined to think that wherever you're creating the "header" is where the problem is, if you're expecting it to be correctly sized already.

Comment: I don't know if I need to resize image ,Inbelow pie method working fine. Second image's position is determine by this canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null).

Comment: Yes, I know how those methods work. I am saying that wherever you're creating `bmp2` is likely where the problem is.

Comment: I update the post. can you review view to bitmap method .

Comment: That doesn't really help to pinpoint the problem. We have no idea how or when you're calling these methods. Have you debugged at all? Are the values passed into `viewtoBitmap()` correct? As an aside, why are you using a `View` for that header? Why don't you just draw a grey rectangle and those two texts with the `Canvas` in your `overlay()` method?

Comment: I checked all passing and got bitmap . I got corresponding proper bitmap if i save only one of the bitmap from overly method. thank for suggestion i will try drawing gray rectangle stuff .

Answer (score 0):

Below function working fine in Pie(9) and Q(10) Devices :

```
public static Bitmap mergeBitmap(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
```